# How to count elements of lists within lists

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have some list of lists of coordinates, i.e.

```
list={{{0,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}},{{3,2},{2,3},{1,4},{0,5}},{{3,1},{2,2},{2,4},{3,5}}}
```

how can I count how many of the y coordinates in each of the lists has a value of 2 or greater? E.g. the first list has 3 y coordinates greater than or equal to 2, the second has 4 and the third has 3. I have tried

```
list1=list[[All, All, 2]]
Count[Map[list1], u_ /; u > 2]
```

but this isn't correctly separating my data by list.

Comment: Try this: `Count[#, x_ /; x[[2]] >= 2, 1] & /@ list`.

Comment: That's great thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
Total[UnitStep[list[[All,All,2]]-2],{2}]
```

> {3, 4, 3}

Answer (score 4):

Here is another version using `Count` (another one is given in a comment):

```
Count[{_, _?(GreaterEqualThan[2])}] /@ list
```

And another one that I also like:

```
Count[{_, y_ /; y >= 2}] /@ list
```

Putting the condition close to the variable makes it clear what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

```
Length@*Select[# >= 2 &] /@ list[[All, All, 2]]

Map[Length@*Select[# >= 2 &]][list[[All, All, 2]]] (* as operator form *)

CountsBy[# >= 2 &] /@ list[[All, All, 2]] // KeyDrop[False] // 
  Values // Flatten

Map[CountsBy[Last@# >= 2 &], list] // KeyDrop[False] // 
  Values // Flatten

Map[Last, list, {2}] // Map[Select[# >= 2 &]] // Map[Length] (* readable *)

list /. {a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ} :> b // 
  DeleteCases[#, _?(# < 2 &), 2] & // Map[Length]

(Scan[If[Last@# >= 2, Sow[Last@#], Nothing] &, #] // Reap // Last // 
     First // Length) & /@ list
```

---

*Result*

{3, 4, 3}

Answer (score 2):

```
Length /@ Replace[list, x_ /; Last[x] < 2 :> Nothing, {2}]
```

{3, 4, 3}

Answer (score 2):

In a shorter way, using `Cases`:

```
Map[Length@Cases[#, {_, y_} /; y >= 2] &]@list
(*Thanks, Eldo!*)

(*{3, 4, 3}*)
```

Also, an alternative using `GroupBy`:

```
Map[Length]@Keys@GroupBy[list, Map[If[#[[2]] >= 2, #[[2]], Nothing] &]]

(*{3, 4, 3}*)
```

Comment: +1 - You can further shorten it since the `Level` specification is redundant: `Length@Cases[#, {_, y_} /; y >= 2] & /@ list`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that important detail, @eldo! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) with [`GreaterEqualThan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GreaterEqualThan.html).

With `list` as in OP

```
Query[
  Map[Length]
  , Select[GreaterEqualThan[2]@*Last]
  ]@list
```

> ```
> {3, 4, 3}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some variations on an already exhaustive list of answers:

````
Length@Select[#, #[[2]] >= 2 &] & /@ list
 (* {3, 4, 3} *)

CountsBy[#, #[[2]] >= 2 &][True] & /@ list
 (* {3, 4, 3} *)

Count[# - 1, _?Positive] & /@ list[[All, All, 2]]
 (* {3, 4, 3} *)
```
````